# Struggling with geopy install. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopy

I ran `pip install geopy` and it seemed to install ok, but I couldn't run the following script.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ryan_data")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)
```

That script gives me this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ryans\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19160\137417210.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

  File "C:\Users\ryans\geopy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders'; 'geopy' is not a package
```

I also tried the following three lines to get geopy installed; none worked.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopy
conda install -c conda-forge geopy=2.3.0
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.10
```

The geopy package works fine on another computer that I use, but it doesn't seem to install on the laptop that I am using now. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any idea how I can get this package installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error traceback, you have a file named geopy.py. Your script is attempting to load that file instead of the geopy package.

Rename the geopy.py file to something else.

Comment: Oh, my!! You are right!! I looked for it in a different director and couldn't find it, so I thought I didn't have it. When I looked for it with my Windows Search tool I found it, renamed it, reloaded the geopy library, and now everything works. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Great to hear! The same thing happened to me in the past. Was difficult to debug!!